# jQuery ajax not passing data JSON value

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I am having some issues with the jQuery Ajax function and PHP.

I am checking the existance of the `nav` key in the `$_REQUEST` variable in PHP with code such as this:

```
if ($_REQUEST['nav']) {
    // do something
} else {
    echo 'Please specify NAV.';
}
```

However the above expression *never* evaluates as `nav` is never passed to it and always outputs 'Please specify NAV.'

```
console.log('paramList: ' + paramList);

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/admin/nav_builder/edit.php?act=save&nav_id=<?php echo $nav_id; ?>',
    data: {'nav':paramList},
    dataType: 'json',
    error: function(xhr, err) {                             
        loadLayout();
        hideLoader();
        hideLoaderPalette();
    },
    success: function(data){
        $('.errorMsg').html(data.html);
        hideLoader();
        hideLoaderPalette();
    }
});
```

Using the Firefox Firebug plugin I can see that `paramList` does indeed hold a value, this is:

> paramList:
>   {"section0":{"elem0":{"nav_palette":"text","nav_name":"fdgfdgdfg","nav_url":""},"elem1":{"nav_palette":"category","c_id":"226"}}}

I can't see for the life of my why `nav` is not being passed to the URL provided to the ajax function.

Comment: Have you tried dumping the `$_REQUEST` on the PHP side to see what's actually being populated?

Comment: Is there request in Firebug->Net->XHR? Can you dump it?

Comment: Does it work with `$_POST['nav']` instead of `$_REQUEST['nav']`?

Comment: @AlessandroPezzato No, it doesn't work with `$_POST`, `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST`

Comment: Why are you specifying a POST? Does the server require a POST instead of a GET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to print first if the "nav" parameter if it has a value.

```
echo $_REQUEST['nav'];
```

The other one is that you have used two method in one request.

Just try the following.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/admin/nav_builder/edit.php',
    data: {act:'save', nav_id:'<?php echo $nav_id; ?>', nav:paramList},
    dataType: 'json',
    error: function(xhr, err) {                             
        loadLayout();
        hideLoader();
        hideLoaderPalette();
    },
    success: function(data){
        $('.errorMsg').html(data.html);
        hideLoader();
        hideLoaderPalette();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try $_POST instead. As you're posting the nav contents.

Comment: What is the difference?
$_REQUEST - An associative array that by default contains the contents of $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE.

Comment: $_REQUEST is the combination of $_POST and $_GET and $_COOKIE.

Comment: I'd worry that the querystring built up above could contain something spurious which could poison the well (e.g. I'm not sure what'd happen if in the nav_id there was an ampersand then nav). If you're using $_POST, you KNOW it's a post value you're getting and not anything from a different/subverted source.